# Custom hyperlinks using AvalonEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I'm trying to create custom hyperlinks using AvalonEdit. I've created a generator (based on the sample) which recognizes a syntax  and I can set a Uri:

```
  public class LinkGenerator : VisualLineElementGenerator
  {
    readonly static Regex imageRegex = new Regex(@"<mylink>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    public LinkGenerator()
    {}

    Match FindMatch(int startOffset)
    {
        // fetch the end offset of the VisualLine being generated
        int endOffset = CurrentContext.VisualLine.LastDocumentLine.EndOffset;
        TextDocument document = CurrentContext.Document;
        string relevantText = document.GetText(startOffset, endOffset - startOffset);
        return imageRegex.Match(relevantText);
    }

    /// Gets the first offset >= startOffset where the generator wants to construct
    /// an element.
    /// Return -1 to signal no interest.
    public override int GetFirstInterestedOffset(int startOffset)
    {
        Match m = FindMatch(startOffset);
        return m.Success ? (startOffset + m.Index) : -1;
    }

    /// Constructs an element at the specified offset.
    /// May return null if no element should be constructed.
    public override VisualLineElement ConstructElement(int offset)
    {
        Match m = FindMatch(offset);
        // check whether there's a match exactly at offset
        if (m.Success && m.Index == 0)
        {
            var line = new VisualLineLinkText(CurrentContext.VisualLine, m.Length);

            line.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://google.com");
            return line;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

However there are two issues I can't seem to figure out:

1. What do I pass to VisualLineLinkText constructor to simplify the text to say "MyLink"?
2. Where do I put an event handler that will receive RequestNavigateEventArgs so I can override the click behavior?

Answer (score 5):

I was needing to use Hyperlink style objects in AvalonEdit but only to "Jump To Definition" style uses, not for web hyperlinks. I didn't want a web browser to start and I needed to catch the hyperlink click event myself in code.

To this end, I created a new class that inherits from VisualLineText. It contains a CustomLinkClicked event and this passes a string to the event handler.

```
/// <summary>
/// VisualLineElement that represents a piece of text and is a clickable link.
/// </summary>
public class CustomLinkVisualLineText : VisualLineText
{

    public delegate void CustomLinkClickHandler(string link);

    public event CustomLinkClickHandler CustomLinkClicked;

    private string Link { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets whether the user needs to press Control to click the link.
    /// The default value is true.
    /// </summary>
    public bool RequireControlModifierForClick { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a visual line text element with the specified length.
    /// It uses the <see cref="ITextRunConstructionContext.VisualLine"/> and its
    /// <see cref="VisualLineElement.RelativeTextOffset"/> to find the actual text string.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomLinkVisualLineText(string theLink, VisualLine parentVisualLine, int length)
        : base(parentVisualLine, length)
    {
        RequireControlModifierForClick = true;
        Link = theLink;
    }


    public override TextRun CreateTextRun(int startVisualColumn, ITextRunConstructionContext context)
    {
        TextRunProperties.SetForegroundBrush(Brushes.GreenYellow);
        TextRunProperties.SetTextDecorations(TextDecorations.Underline);
        return base.CreateTextRun(startVisualColumn, context);
    }

    bool LinkIsClickable()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Link))
            return false;
        if (RequireControlModifierForClick)
            return (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control;
        else
            return true;
    }


    protected override void OnQueryCursor(QueryCursorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LinkIsClickable())
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && !e.Handled && LinkIsClickable())
        {

            if (CustomLinkClicked != null)
            {
                CustomLinkClicked(Link);
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }

    protected override VisualLineText CreateInstance(int length)
    {

        var a = new CustomLinkVisualLineText(Link, ParentVisualLine, length)
        {                
            RequireControlModifierForClick = RequireControlModifierForClick
        };

        a.CustomLinkClicked += link => ApplicationViewModel.Instance.ActiveCodeViewDocument.HandleLinkClicked(Link);
        return a;
    }
}
```

As these elements are created and destroyed at runtime dynamically, I had to register the click event to a static instance of a class to handle.

```
a.CustomLinkClicked += link => ApplicationViewModel.Instance.ActiveCodeViewDocument.HandleLinkClicked(Link);
```

When you click on the link (using Ctrl-click if specified), it will fire the event. You could replace the "Link" string with any other class you need. You will need to replace the line 'ApplicationViewModel.Instance.ActiveCodeViewDocument.HandleLinkClicked(Link)' to something you have access to in your code.

Comment: Sorry to dig into this old answer, but "Jump To Definition" style Navigation is exactly what i'm trying to achieve. I just don't get where the "match" happens in your use of VisualLineText. Can i somehow connect this to the Highlighting Engine?

Comment: Nevermind the above comment. Syntax Highlighting happens in the CreateInstance Sub

Comment: I know this is an old question; however, your answer seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Is there some sort of syntax you give the highlight engine? What component is responsible for generating the links?